# How can I avoid my patties bulging in the middle?

Tags: beef, turkey, hamburgers, frying-pan, skillet

When cooking beef or turkey patties on the skillet, I often end up with them bulging in the middle. See photo below. One patty is bulging like crazy, the other is more normal.

[image: Bulging beef patties]

This bulging results in the middle not making contact with the pan, and thus cooking less. Then when I go to flip the patties, the bulge makes the patties tip to one side, making the cooking even more uneven.

Sometimes I cook patties straight out of the freezer, sometimes the fridge. I think the frozen ones bulge more, but not exclusively.

What's the best way to handle this? Should I try cooking with a lower/higher temperature? Or do I need to buy a weight for the patties?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the patty, make a slight indentation in the middle.  That way, the "bulge" will result in a flat patty.  If you purchase patties from the store, and cook from frozen, the only solution will be a weight or heavy pan on top as they cook.

Comment: You can always thin out the middles of the store-bought patties too.